# Resize an own user control

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, wpf-controls

I am creating a Windows Phone application, and I use an own `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Negyzet"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    Width="100" Height="100">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Kitoltoszin" Stroke="White" Width="100" Height="100" StrokeThickness="3" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock  x:Name="Betu" Width="70" Height="70" 
                FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="42" Foreground="White" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And I have Window, where I am generating the controls dynamically, to a `Grid`:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="NegyzetGrid" Background="Transparent">
</Grid>
```

Generating:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    ColumnDefinition col = new ColumnDefinition();
    //NegyzetGrid: where I have to generate the Controls
    NegyzetGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
    NegyzetGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        palya[i, j] = new Negyzet();
        palya[i, j].IsHitTestVisible = false;
        Grid.SetRow(palya[i, j], i);
        Grid.SetColumn(palya[i, j], j);
        NegyzetGrid.Children.Add(palya[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Depending on what the user chooses, I have to generate 3x3, 4x4, or 5x5 items. I want to create a multi-resolution app, and I want to auto-size my own controls to fill the whole screen, and each of the controls has to be of the same size. (For example, if I have a 900 pixels wide screen, and the user chooses 3x3, then the items width has to be 300, if 4x4, then 225 and so on.)

How can I set the size like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment like this in the window. By doing this your grid will take all the available space :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="NegyzetGrid" Background="Transparent">

</Grid>
```

And then in the user control delete the width and height int the UserControl declaration and set VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment property on the Rectangle to Stretch, that should do the trick !  :

```
<UserControl x:Class="ST1.Negyzet"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Kitoltoszin" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="3" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <TextBlock  x:Name="Betu" Width="70" Height="70" 
               FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="42" Foreground="White" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```